# how i can solve "TypeError: string indices must be integers? " when check if the key exist in the dict

Tags: python

i want to check if the input key match with Dictionaries

```
def update_details():
    input_detais = input("please select which feild you want to change ")   
    for detais in store_group_details:
        if detais['type'] == input_detais:  
            print ("exist")
```

her the store_group_details

```
store_group_details={'app_group3': ['calculater', 'google'],
 'Date': '2022-02-14',
 'Time': '03:00:00', 
'group name': 'test1'}
```

Comment: what is the type of the `detais` object?

Comment: It seems that `details` is a string that you mistakenly think is a dictionary. Without a [mcve] we can do no more than guess why that might be.

Comment: yes i update the question and add store_group_details dict

Answer (score 0):

i solve the question

```
def update_details():
    input_detais = input("please select which field you want to change: ")
    for detais in store_group_details:
        if detais == input_detais:  # removed ['type']
            print("existing")
```